# How can I match 2 file csv?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, matching

```
file 1
column: id  name   city   work 
row:    123 Mark Chicago baker

file 2
column: id  name work  age
row:    123 Mark baker  27
```

I want match two file adding at the output the column "age".

```
file output

column: id   name    city       work       age
row:    123  Mark    Chicago    baker       27
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` [library](http://pandas.pydata.org/) something like this

```
import pandas

def main():
 file1 = pandas.read_csv("file1.csv")
 file2 = pandas.read_csv("file2.csv")
 file2 = file2.dropna(axis=1)
 output = file1.merge(file2, on='id')
 output.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Hope this will help you (y).

Comment: yes, this is very usefull but the program print only the first row. Do you know how can i print all database?